# Fuzzy find within buffer

Tags: find

Can I change `/` command to execute a fuzzy search instead of a regex based one?

It would be useful to still be able to access the classic `/` functionality at certain times.

Comment: If you have a fuzzy find plugin I suppose you could just remap `/`, `n`, `N`, etc. to whatever key(s) bring up search prompt and go forward/back for that. But you won't be able to fundamentally change the native search.

Comment: @BLayer what fuzzy find plugins are there?

Comment: Here https://superuser.com/questions/390011/fuzzy-find-within-file-in-vim ... not a lot of choices.

Comment: also there are a few options like ignorecase/smartcase that make search a little bit less strict

Comment: You can use [VimAwesome](https://vimawesome.com/) to help search for [fuzzy plugins](https://vimawesome.com/?q=fuzzy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://github.com/ggvgc/vim-fuzzysearch

Then simply...

```
nnoremap / :FuzzySearch<CR>
let g:fuzzysearch_prompt = '/'
```

Then `/` will take you to a prompt where you enter your pattern and it all looks just like normal Vim. I believe  From there `n` and `N` will work without modification.

If they aren't already enabled then `set incsearch` and, possibly, `set hlsearch` as they enhance that "fuzzy search feeling".

You can optionally tune some other things per your preferences with these settings:

```
g:fuzzysearch_hlsearch = 1
g:fuzzysearch_ignorecase = 1   
g:fuzzysearch_max_history = 30
g:fuzzysearch_match_spaces = 0
```

Note that the core functionality of this plugin is pretty simple. It just alters your search term so non-space characters (if `g:fuzzysearch_match_spaces` is 1 then *any* characters) are allowed between the characters *you* enter and submits the updated pattern to native Vim search. But I just tried it and it felt like a decent approach.

To go back to native search `nunmap /`. You can map the `nnoremap` and `nunmap` commands to Normal mode shortcuts to make it really convenient to toggle between the search modes.

Comment: Even with `g:fuzzysearch_match_spaces` set to `1` it seems to not match phrases like `hi there` when searching `hh` (for example)

Comment: Hmm. I'll take a look when I get a chance. In the meantime `h h` should work for that example.